# Why can't my device connect over WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi

Here is the steps to connect my Android phone from PC over WiFi:

1.Connect the device and the computer to the same Wi-Fi network
2.Plug the device to the computer with a USB cable to configure the connection
3.On the computer command line type:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

4.On the computer command line type:

```
adb shell ip addr show wlan0 
#i get the phones ip----192.168.31.86
```

5.On the computer command line type:

```
adb connect 192.168.31.86:5555
connected to 192.168.31.86:5555
```

6.Disconnect the USB cable from the device and check with adb devices

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.31.86:5555  offline
```

Why the status is not online when to disconnect the USB cable from my phone?

Comment: Does your computer has an IP in the same subnet? Can you ping your phone from your PC? Make sure in your WiFi router communication between clients is allowed, a lot of routers disallow this by default.

Comment: FYI, the feature @robert mentioned at the end is called "network isolation" on some routers.

Answer (score 0):

I replace 5555 port with other number to solve the issue.